# members() of a list

Tags: list, prolog, member

There is the the `member()`, but is there `members()` predicate?
Which accept two lists and checks/unifies if the elements in the one list are members of the other list?

```
 members([2,4], [1,2,3,4,5])  => true

 members([2,X], [1,2,3,4,5])  =probably=> [2,1];[2,3];[2,4];[2,5]
```

or probably it should behave like :

```
 members([2,4], [1,2,3,4,5])  => member([2], [1,2,3,4,5]),member([4], [1,2,3,4,5])
```

I'm looking for the second interpretation, but the first non procedural implementation!

=====

second interpretation probably :

```
  ?- Y=[1,2,3,4,5],maplist( \X^(member(X,Y)),[2,4,5]).
```

Comment: Why don't you write the procedure yourself ?

Comment: because there too many possible interpretations and dont know how ? thought someone more experienced can forsee all the possibilities. the second interpretation just now figured out i can use maplist may be !

Comment: Why can't the query ```?- members([2,X],[1,2,3,4,5])``` produce answer ```[2,2]```? Are you supposing that ```[2,X]``` must be a subset of ```[1,2,3,4,5]```?

Comment: because it matched once i.e true

Comment: is it for sets or for lists? example: what would produce members([1,X],[1,1,2])?

Comment: It sounds to be that what you're looking for is generating the _**permutations**_ (ordered) or _**combinations**_ of a list of _**n**_ things taken _**k**_ at a time. See https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations_and_permutations

Comment: hmm.. interesting idea ... thanks